# Struggling with Keylisteners (Java)

Tags: java, game-development

I've been following TheCherno's tutorial series on java game development. He uses sprites for only four directions, whereas I want to use for 8 ( up+right etc.)
I've been trying to get the code to return booleans for when two of the directional keys are pressed and I seem to have hit a stump, I'm not sure what to do next. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

    private Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<Character>();
    public boolean up, down, left, right, upright, downright, downleft, upleft;

    public void update() {
        for (Character c : pressed) {
            if (c == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                left = true;
            } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                down = true;
            } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                right = true;
            } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                up = true;
            }
        }

        if (up && right) upright = true;
        if (down && right) downright = true;
        if (down && left) downleft = true;
        if (up && left) upleft = true;

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

        pressed.remove(e.getKeyChar());

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What’s calling update?

Comment: It's being called in my main class, in the game loop. I think that's what you're asking, right?

Comment: You don't state what the problem actually is (i.e. what you're expecting and what is happening). I guess that after a while the key state gets stuck. And the cause seems to be that none of the booleans (up, down, left, right, upright, downright, downleft, upleft) get ever reset: they never get set to false after the key is released. So if after calling `update()` you check for their status, the first thing that `update()` should do is set all of those Booleans to false. (also beware of concurrent access and multithreading).

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense, and would probably have hit that problem if it worked as intended. But right now, none of them seem to be set to true when I press any of the keys.

Comment: @AbjectFailure Do the `keyPressed` or other methods get called? If not, check how the event listener is being added. Include that code in the question. If they are, make sure the game loop is calling update before checking those booleans. (I don't know who TheCherno is or his tutorials, so can't compare to his code)